# How to render clear checkbox manually in Django Forms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

In Django when dealing with an image in a form, there is always this clear checkbox (if the image is nullable), e.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="image_var-clear" id="image_var-clear_id">
<label for="image_var-clear_id">Clear</label>
```

Now, I wish to render it manually. If I place "{{ form.image_var }}" in my HTML, the checkbox appears and the above html code is generated, but I cannot figure out how to render it completely manually. So far I managed to get these values:

```
if required: {{ form.image_var.field.required }}
checkbox label: {{ form.image_var.field.widget.clear_checkbox_label }}
input text: {{ form.image_var.field.widget.input_text }}
checkbox name: {{ form.image_var.field.widget.name }}
text: {{ form.image_var.field.widget.initial_text }}
```

This all works fine, until I want to render the checkbox_id with:

`{{ form.image_var.field.widget.checkbox_id }}`

What am I missing?

Comment: Which error do you get? It looks correct.

Comment: I don't get any error per sé, it simply does not render the checkbox_id when calling {{ form.image_var.field.widget.checkbox_id }}. So there must be some kind of variation of the syntax to get the checkbox_id.